# Pass Model OnEventClick in Syncfusion Schedular Asp.net Blazor

Tags: c#, syncfusion, asp.net-blazor

Can I send  Model to a specific date I mean all data of a schedular . I am using Syncfusion Schedular. Here is my code

```
<SfSchedule TValue="AppointmentData" SelectedDateChanged="CommandDateChanged" Width="100%" Height="600px" EnableAutoRowHeight="true" SelectedDate="@DateTime.Now" DateFormat="yyyy/MM/dd" @bind-CurrentView="@CurrentView">
          
            <ScheduleResources>
                <ScheduleResource TItem="ResourceData" TValue="int" DataSource="@ProjectData" Field="Id" TextField="Text" ColorField="Color">

                </ScheduleResource>
            </ScheduleResources>
            <ScheduleEvents TValue="AppointmentData"  OnPopupOpen="@OnPopupOpen" OnCellClick="OnCellClickAsync" OnEventClick="OnEventClick" ></SfSchedule>
```

I want to pass OnEventClick in this event to current cell data. Here is my C# code

```
 public async Task OnEventClick(EventClickArgs<AppointmentData> args)
    {

        //var tt=AppointmentData.
      //  var tt = args.Description;
       // args.cancel = true;
       // await ScheduleRef.OpenEditor(args.Event, CurrentAction.Save);   //To open the editor on event click
    }
```

I want to get the current data of AppointmentData.description . Here is AppointmentData class

```
 public class AppointmentData
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool IsAllDay { get; set; }
        public string RecurrenceRule { get; set; }
        public string RecurrenceException { get; set; }
        public int RecurrenceID { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to get the current selected cell description and other data how to get from Synfusion Schedular. Please Note that in a empty cell I  use OnCellClick but where The data has I use
OnEventClick event.  Please see the picture if you do not understand
[image]

How to get the model data?

Answer (score 0):

You will get the event model in **Event** property of **OnEventClick** event.

```
public void OnEventClick(EventClickArgs<AppointmentData> args)
{
    AppointmentData eventData = args.Event;
}
```